# How can I trigger an event in zen cart when a payment is complete?

Tags: php, shopping-cart, zen-cart

I wrote some custom stuff so I can send an email with some various data to a customer when their order has completed. The problem is, I can't seem to find where or when I can verify that the payment has been processed successfully.

I tried triggering the event using:

```
payment::after_process()
```

but that appears to fire when the *order* has processed, not the payment. I need to be sure the customer has paid before triggering this event.

Where can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DrByte](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/member.php?u=6) over at zen-cart.com [answered my question](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1018530#post1018530).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just customize includes/classes/order.php and modify send_order_email().  You have the order id so you can verify that the status is Processing (or something other than Pending) so you know the payment has been accepted.

Comment: This or something like it apparently works great with all modules except for remote-hosted payment processing services (ex. PayPal IPN).. which my client happened to be using.